# Implement From on a trait which has Self as member

Tags: rust, traits

I want to be able to convert any iterator into `MyType`.

```
impl<T, I: IntoIterator<Item = T>> From<I> for MyType<T>
```

As in

```
MyType<T>::from<I: IntoIterator>(iter: I) -> MyType<T>
```

As one expects, it makes sense for `MyType` to itself be convertible to an `Iterator` and satisfy `IntoIterator` as a trait, and it does.

But `From` is automatically implemented reflexively for any type, any type can convert into itself of course, and this is where the compiler barks:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait 
`std::convert::From<MyType<_>>` for type `MyType<_>`:
```

My generic implementation for all `IntoIterators` conflicts with the default one. If Rust did not provide a default one then it would actually work albeit being needlessly expensive.

Is there any way to implement the trait for any member of `IntoIterator` except `MyType`?

Comment: Cross-posted on [r/rust](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/5tfrfc/implementation_for_trait_that_is_already_provided/).

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a precedent in the Rust standard library: [`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) is about creating a new value from an iterator.

Following this model, rather than implementing [`std::convert::From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html), you should implement [`std::iter::FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html).

And then there will be no conflict.